# После нажатия на checkbox можно нажать на f7 и текст кнопки измениться

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

На форуме нашел вопрос связанный с `checkbox` я попробовал сделать такую функцию.

После нажатия на `checkbox` открывается такая возможность как - после нажатия клавиши `F7` текст кнопки должен измениться на **Hello**, но если же галочка не стоит то эта функция не должна работать .

Как это сделать?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(658, 229)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 110, 201, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 50, 70, 18))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 658, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu75 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu75.setObjectName("menu75")
        self.menuytr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menu75)
        self.menuytr.setObjectName("menuytr")
        self.menutryr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuytr)
        self.menutryr.setObjectName("menutryr")
        self.menurtyr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menutryr)
        self.menurtyr.setObjectName("menurtyr")
        self.menutryrt = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menurtyr)
        self.menutryrt.setObjectName("menutryrt")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionrtyrty = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionrtyrty.setObjectName("actionrtyrty")
        self.menutryrt.addAction(self.actionrtyrty)
        self.menurtyr.addAction(self.menutryrt.menuAction())
        self.menutryr.addAction(self.menurtyr.menuAction())
        self.menuytr.addAction(self.menutryr.menuAction())
        self.menu75.addAction(self.menuytr.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu75.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.menu75.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "75"))
        self.menuytr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ytr"))
        self.menutryr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "tryr"))
        self.menurtyr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "rtyr"))
        self.menutryrt.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "tryrt"))
        self.actionrtyrty.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rtyrty"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(658, 229)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 110, 201, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 50, 70, 18))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 658, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu75 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu75.setObjectName("menu75")
        self.menuytr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menu75)
        self.menuytr.setObjectName("menuytr")
        self.menutryr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuytr)
        self.menutryr.setObjectName("menutryr")
        self.menurtyr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menutryr)
        self.menurtyr.setObjectName("menurtyr")
        self.menutryrt = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menurtyr)
        self.menutryrt.setObjectName("menutryrt")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionrtyrty = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionrtyrty.setObjectName("actionrtyrty")
        self.menutryrt.addAction(self.actionrtyrty)
        self.menurtyr.addAction(self.menutryrt.menuAction())
        self.menutryr.addAction(self.menurtyr.menuAction())
        self.menuytr.addAction(self.menutryr.menuAction())
        self.menu75.addAction(self.menuytr.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu75.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.menu75.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "75"))
        self.menuytr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ytr"))
        self.menutryr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "tryr"))
        self.menurtyr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "rtyr"))
        self.menutryrt.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "tryrt"))
        self.actionrtyrty.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rtyrty"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkboxChanged)

    def checkboxChanged(self, state):  
        if not state:
            self.pushButton.setText("PushButton")

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):                                 
        if QKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F7 and self.checkBox.isChecked():
            self.pushButton.setText("Hello World")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> А как сделать так - если я после того как я нажал F7 и после этого нажму еще раз F7 то текст обратно станет Pushbutton, пробовал через else:, не работает

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(658, 229)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 110, 201, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 50, 70, 18))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 658, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu75 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu75.setObjectName("menu75")
        self.menuytr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menu75)
        self.menuytr.setObjectName("menuytr")
        self.menutryr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuytr)
        self.menutryr.setObjectName("menutryr")
        self.menurtyr = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menutryr)
        self.menurtyr.setObjectName("menurtyr")
        self.menutryrt = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menurtyr)
        self.menutryrt.setObjectName("menutryrt")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionrtyrty = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionrtyrty.setObjectName("actionrtyrty")
        self.menutryrt.addAction(self.actionrtyrty)
        self.menurtyr.addAction(self.menutryrt.menuAction())
        self.menutryr.addAction(self.menurtyr.menuAction())
        self.menuytr.addAction(self.menutryr.menuAction())
        self.menu75.addAction(self.menuytr.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu75.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.menu75.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "75"))
        self.menuytr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "ytr"))
        self.menutryr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "tryr"))
        self.menurtyr.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "rtyr"))
        self.menutryrt.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "tryrt"))
        self.actionrtyrty.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rtyrty"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkboxChanged)

    def checkboxChanged(self, state):  
        if not state:
            self.pushButton.setText("PushButton")

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):                                 
        if QKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F7 and self.checkBox.isChecked():
            if self.pushButton.text() == "Hello World":
                self.pushButton.setText("PushButton")
            else:
                self.pushButton.setText("Hello World")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А как сделать так - если я после того как я нажал F7 и после этого нажму еще раз F7 то текст обратно станет Pushbutton, пробовал через else:, не работает

Comment: @ДимаНейзвестный я дополнил ответ, пробуйте